# Why doesn't the definition of the interior of a set depend on the dimension of the set

Tags: convex-analysis

I have just started with a course on convex optimization and have been introduced to the concept of the interior of a set. I have a fairly basic question. I am still trying to understand this topic, so please forgive me if this is a stupid or incorrect question.

Why is not the definition of the interior of a set not tied to the dimension of the space it is lying in?

For e.g. Consider a square in $\mathbb{R}^2$ i.e. $\mathcal{S} = \{(x,y)|x\in[-1,1],y\in[-1,1]\}$. By definition, points inside the square are interior points, because all points within an open '${disc}$' of radius $\epsilon>0$, around the point under consideration, lie inside the set.

But in 3 dimensions, this 2D figure has $\varnothing$ interior, since all points inside an open '$ball$' around any of the points inside $\mathcal{S}$, do not belong to $\mathcal{S}$

So, shouldn't the definition of the interior of a set be tied to the dimension of the space from which we are looking at the set? Else, how does one know whether to use a disc or a ball to find the interior of a set.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That would be the concept of relative interior ($\operatorname{ri}$), which is the interior relative to the affine hull of the set in question. Unfortunately $\operatorname{ri}$ has a few quirks that make it easy to trip on. For example, if $A \subset B$ it follows that $A^\circ \subset B^\circ$, but the same does not necessarily apply to $\operatorname{ri}$.

Comment: The definition of interior _does_ depend on the space you're working in (in exactly the ways you mentioned). What definition have you seen?

Comment: Better to speak not of spheres, but of *open balls* (sometimes called *open discs*). The *sphere* is just the surface of the ball; notice, for example, JackM's answer does not mention spheres.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Thank you for your answer. The definition was from the book Convex optimization, Boyd and from Wikipedia. Both of them mentioned an open sphere without mentioning the dimension.

Comment: @goblin Have made the edit. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct; the context in which interiors are taken matters.

It is a mathematical meteprinciple that the way to formalize "widening of context" is by leveraging the concept of an [embedding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding). Nobody has (so far) proposed a definition of embedding that works in all cases, but the correct definition for metric spaces is surely that of an [isometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry), sometimes called an *isometric embedding*. (Note: isometries are always injective; however, contrary to what you might expect from the prefix iso-, they needn't be invertible, nor surjective.)

The importance of context for the taking of interiors can therefore be phrased as follows. Let $X$ and $Y$ denote metric spaces, and suppose $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is an isometry (i.e. an isometric embedding, in other words a widening of context). Then given a subset $S \subseteq X$, all we can say is that $f(\mathrm{int}(S)) \supseteq \mathrm{int}(f(S)).$ In particular, **the reverse inclusion needn't hold.**

Here's a simple example, a slight variant on the example you give. Bind the variables $u$ and $v$ to the real number line. Take $X = \mathbb{R}^2, \,Y = \mathbb{R}^3$, and let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ denote the function specified as follows. $$f(u,v) = (u,v,0)$$

(Check that this is an isometry; i.e. a widening of context.)

Now let $S \subseteq X$ be defined as follows. $$S=\{(u,v) \in X\,|\,u∈(−1,1),v∈(−1,1)\}$$

Then:

1. $\mathrm{int}(S) = S,$ so $f(\mathrm{int}(S)) = \{(u,v,0) \in Y\,|\,u∈(−1,1),v∈(−1,1)\},$ which is not empty.
2. On the other hand, we have $f(S) = \{(u,v,0) \in Y\,|\,u∈(−1,1),v∈(−1,1)\},$ so $\mathrm{int}(f(S)) = \emptyset_Y$.

So yes, context matters. It is considerations such as these that led to the by-now dominant way of looking at mathematical structures. If we're thinking of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ as metric spaces, then we imagine them "floating free" in the universe. We do *not* imagine that $\mathbb{R}^2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$. Rather, there are many embeddings $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, and each of these gives us a way of viewing $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$. But these $f$'s are not harmless; as we've just seen, widening the context actually *changes* things; some constructions are preserved under embeddings, but many are not.

Comment: I loved your answer. Especially the last paragraph. I quite did not understand how you arrived at $f(\mathrm{int}(S)) \supseteq \mathrm{int}(f(S))$.

Comment: @KarthikUpadhya, to be honest, I can't quite see how to prove this. I'll edit when I think of the proof, if I do not forget. And thank you for the kind words. You're awesome.

Answer (score 4):

The definition of the interior is:

> A point $x$ is in the interior of $S$ iff it can be surrounded by an *open ball* lying entirely inside $S$.

The reference to dimension is hiding inside the term 
*open ball*. In two dimensions, this is a disk, in three dimensions a literal ball, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But my question is precisely this. If one is asked to find the interior of a set, what dimension should he assume?

Comment: @KarthikUpadhya, this is very hard to explain in a Q&A format, because its a subtle point, and mathematics is full of abuses of notation that make the point even *more* subtle. I really need to be there in person so we can have a conversation. This is the only way to explain it properly. But let me try anyway. You don't *need* to know the dimension.What you need is a change of *perspective.* The relevant perspective is this.

Comment: Firstly, $\mathbb{R}^2$ is **not** a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$; they should be imagined as disjoint. Secondly, $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not on equal footing with its subsets. A subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ "remembers" that it is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. On the other hand, $\mathbb{R}^2$ "floats free" in the universe. So if $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $\mathrm{int}(S)$ is unambiguous; we're taking the interior in $\mathbb{R}^2,$ because $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, because it *remembers* that it is a subset. Have a look at my answer again, especially the last paragraph.

Comment: Also, @KarthikUpadhya, make sure you're familiar with the definition of a [metric space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space), since this is the basic concept necessary to understand all the rest.

Comment: @KarthikUpadhya If you ask me to find the interior of a set, I need to know what topology you're using. In other words, you need to *tell me* explicitly what dimension to use.

Comment: @JackM Got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The idea of the interior is a concept from the world of topology. It is designed to work with things where you don't (yet) even have an idea of what dimension means. On the other hand, as mentioned in the comments, the definition is (intentionally) depended on what topological space you are looking at -- a square in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is distinct from a square in $\mathbb{R}^3$ because $\mathbb{R}^2$ is different from $\mathbb{R}^3$. To make sense of interior, you must consider the set of interest together with the whole space it is lying in.